# One-parameter Infinitesimal transformation with m dependent variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, lie-groups

I have been trying to find out how to write the one-parameter Infinitesimal transformation $Uf$ (Lie's continuous groups) with n dependent variables, so far without success.

Abraham Cohen, "An introduction to the Lie theory of one-parameter groups" gives the expression for infinitesimal transformation for one dependent variable $y$ and $n$ independent variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$:

Given is the point transformation

$$x_k^{\prime}=\phi_k(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y,a), \mbox{   } k=1...n$$
$$y^{\prime}=\psi(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y,a)$$

where $a$ is the parameter of the group.

Then, if $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y)$ is a smooth function and has the needed partial derivatives, the (non extended) infinitesimal transformation of $f$ is given by

$$Uf=\xi_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}+\xi_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}+...+\xi_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}+\eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},$$ where

$$\xi_k=\left ( \frac{\partial \phi_k}{\partial a} \right )_{a_0}$$
$$\eta=\left ( \frac{\partial \psi}{\partial a} \right )_{a_0}$$
and $a_0$ is the value of the parameter which yields identity.

Now, how does one write the (non extended)
 $Uf$ when we have $m$ dependent variables $y_1,y_2,...,y_m$? Also, what would be a good text to read up more about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at the [FAS site](https://fas.org/sgp/othergov/doe/lanl/lib-www/la-pubs/00296541.pdf),
in the pdf file on page 33. ('Lie Group Invariant Finite Difference Schemes
for the Neutron Difusion Equation', by Peter James Jaegers)

Given is the point transformation

$$x_k^{\prime}=\phi_k(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y_1,y_2,...,y_m,a), \mbox{   } k=1...n$$
$$y_l^{\prime}=\psi_l(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y_1,y_2,...,y_m,a), \mbox{   } l=1...m$$
where $a$ is the parameter of the group.

Then, if $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n,y_1,y_2,...,y_m,a)$ is a smooth function and has the needed partial derivatives, the (non extended) infinitesimal transformation of $f$ is given by

$$Uf=\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_k\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}+\sum_{l=1}^m \eta_l\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_l},$$ where

$$\xi_k=\left ( \frac{\partial \phi_k}{\partial a} \right )_{a_0}$$
$$\eta_l=\left ( \frac{\partial \psi_l}{\partial a} \right )_{a_0}$$
and $a_0$ is the value of the parameter which yields identity.

Comment: It took me a day's time to find this answer...